# "Back to Top" link accessibility

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility

I am working on a web page where user has to scroll a lot.

For ease of use, I have added the back-to-top link at the bottom of the page, so user can navigate to the top of the page.

Now I have a html markup like this:

```
<a class="btn-primary" href="#top">
<span class="btn-content link-content">
<svg focusable="false"><use xlink:href="#arrow-upward"></use></svg>
</span>
</a>
```

How can I make my link more accessible? I have thought of adding `aria-label`, but other than that nothing crosses my mind

Comment: It needs text. How you implement it is up to you.

Comment: @isherwood What kind of text, its just has svg icon of and arrow inside the link by design

Comment: You suggested one solution yourself. Another is to visually hide the text with CSS. Your question isn't clear.

Comment: Using `aria-label` is all you need, if you don't want text in the link itself. When screen readers come across the link, it will read the aria-label.

Comment: What do you mean by "more accessible"? More accessible than what? Is there an objective standard you are trying to meet? This is currently unanswerable objectively.

Comment: I’m curious: Where did you get the `focusable` attribute from? I keep seeing it in questions, but it’s not part of the HTML spec.

Comment: @Andy - https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/interact.html#focusable-attr

Comment: See "[Do people use `jump to top of page` links?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/20663/22571)"

Comment: That’s a great reference @outis. Even though the answer to that question is quite outdated. See https://www.nngroup.com/articles/back-to-top/

Comment: @Andy: would you post an updated answer?

Comment: I already did. On the very top I included NNg’s article

Answer (score 2):

First of all, render your component usable, for example by following [NNg’s Back-to-Top Button Design Guidelines](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/back-to-top/). This is a solid basis. Thanks to @outis for the hint.

Here are some accessibility concerns that come to mind with regards to such a Back to top component.

### Alternative text/accessible name

Every interactive element needs an accessible name. This text is not only what gets read by a screen reader when focussing the element, but also how voice control can identify the button, as in “Click on back to top”.

### Accompanying text for sighted users

Adding a tooltip for sighted users via the `title` attribute is always a good idea as well, but you should never rely on that attribute to provide an accessible name, as implementation in screen readers is not good.

Even better would be having the text always visible for everyone. [Not everyone gets icons correctly](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/icon-usability/).

That way you also provide a very visible hint to voice command users.
The [visible part needs to be included in the accessible name](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG22/Understanding/label-in-name.html) (alt text) for this reason. You should add `role="presentation"` to the SVG if you have accessible text next to it.

[image: An up arrow followed by the words Back to top]

*This is an example from the [GOV.UK Design System Guidelines](https://design-system.service.gov.uk/community/), who care a great deal about accessibility. They add it just before the footer on long pages.*

### Contrast

Since you didn’t share your CSS, we don’t know what it does with colours. You need to make sure that the icon and text’s contrast with the background are still 4.5:1 or above.

### Avoid icon-fonts

You already got that right. (:

Since users with reading disorders often make their browser use a font they can read well, icon-fonts will break and remove icons that—ironically—would help them most.

### Be careful with animated scroll

Often developers (or designers?) like to fly back to the top instead of the instant jump. This can help users orientate.

Nowadays we can simply specify this with [`scroll-behaviour: smooth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior) and let the browser do the work.

However you implement this, you should be careful to not cause vertigo in people who are sensitive to these zoom animations. Only apply this if the user *can* and *did not* set [`prefers-reduced-motion`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion)

### Focus

While it is important to include the button in the tab order, it should probably come right before the footer, even when it’s visible all the time.

Focus needs to be visible, of course, as for all interactive elements.

Keyboard users can easily jump back to top by using their <kbd>Home</kbd> key, so it’s less important to have the button in early in focus order or after each chapter or something.

When the button disappears when arriving on top, focus needs to be put somewhere else, it must not be “lost” (going to body or html).

### Refer to the WCAG

I might have missed some criteria in this answer.

If you want to be sure, you can open up the [WCAG-EM Report Tool](https://www.w3.org/WAI/eval/report-tool/) and start creating a report for your component.

All criteria of the Web Content Accessibility Criteria will need to be audited by you. This is the industry standard for accessible web applications, and legally binding in a lot of states.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the Title attribute in your anchor tag

```
<a class="btn-primary" href="#top" title="go to top of page">
```

Comment: Mobile users and keyboard only users (a user who navigates without a mouse) cannot fire the event to show the value of the title attribute.

Source: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-title-attribute

Answer (score 0):

When working on the in-page navigation links, we should not forget the screen reader users, so we must ensure they know the purpose of the link. A common way is an aria-label attribute specifying a meaningful value, such as 'Go to top' or 'Back to top'. Once the aria-label is specified, the content of the link should be hidden from the screen reader (Exceptions exist) i.e.: via aria-hidden='true' .

Another detail that should not be forgotten is the focus handling. By default, most of the browsers just scroll the page when using an *#Element's_ID* for the href if the id does not exist, and SR/Keyboard users will be affected in such a way that after the page is scrolled to top and Tab key is pressed the focus will move to the next focusable element before the page was scrolled up, so, the result will be, an undesired page scroll down.

There is a working implementation in W3C patterns page https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/.

Hope this helps in your accessibility journey. The a11y world needs lot of people interested on it.

```
    <body id="top">
    ...
      <a class="btn-primary" aria-label="Back to top" href="#top">...
      </a>
...
    </body>
```

Comment: Consider using "visually hidden" text instead of aria-label. The value of the attribute isn't translated most of the times : https://adrianroselli.com/2019/11/aria-label-does-not-translate.html